# How to define time-dependent rate in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic, systemdynamics

I want to define a production rate for crops in farms just for 3 month for example just summer not for a year. I want to model produced crops in System dynamics. Is there any option to define time-dependent flow rate in Anylogic?

I am looking for some option in Anylogic to define time-dependent rate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple variable and change its values with cyclic events, i.e. turn it to "1" 3 months after model start (then every 12 months). Turn it to "0" 9 months after model start, then every 12 months -> got a seasonal fluctuation